# Problems with libmcrypt in C

Tags: c, mcrypt

I have a client server program in C that encrypts/decrypts data with mcrypt library. The client encrypts the string that wants to send to server, send it, and after the server reads, decrypts it. Bellow are my encrypt and decrypt function:

**encrypt function:**

```
void encrypt(char *es, char *key, char *civ, size_t  length) {

    MCRYPT td;
    int n;

    td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, NULL, MCRYPT_CFB, NULL );
    if (td == MCRYPT_FAILED) {
        log_err(log_opts, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    n = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td);

    char iv[n + 1];
    strncpy(iv, civ, n);
    iv[n] = '\0';

    if ((mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, KEY_SIZE, iv)) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "while trying to do mcrypt_generic_init.");
        exit(1);
    }
    mcrypt_generic(td, es, length);

    if (mcrypt_module_close(td) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "while trying to close module.");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

**decrypt function**

```
void decrypt(char *ds, char *key, char *civ, size_t length) {
    MCRYPT td;
    int n;

    td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, NULL, MCRYPT_CFB, NULL );
    n = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td);

    char iv[n + 1];
    strncpy(iv, civ, n);
    iv[n + 1] = '\0';

    if ((mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, KEY_SIZE, iv)) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "trying to do mcrypt_generic_init.");
        exit(1);
    }

    mdecrypt_generic(td, ds, length);
    if (mcrypt_module_close(td) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "while trying to close module.");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

**My problem:**

There are cases (1 to 10 rate) when a string decrypted on server side but encrypted on client side is not the same like original. Can anyone suggest my where the problem can come from?

---

**EDIT**

The response to this question, you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183004/is-libmcrypt-not-reliable#18205480), where this issue is also detailed further, being pointed out the code that contains the bug.

Comment: are you sure you receive all data? what type of client/server architecture do you use? internet sockets?

Comment: @robin.koch yes. socket to socket communication. Anyway, I verified to see if the string that server reads is the same with the string that client writes, and from this point of view, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used string functions on raw bytes array. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183004/is-libmcrypt-not-reliable#18205480) link for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In `decrypt` function:

```
char iv[n + 1];
strncpy(iv, civ, n);
iv[n + 1] = '\0';
```

You have an off-by-one overflow in `iv[n + 1] = '\0';` statement.