# Is libmcrypt not reliable?

Tags: c, mcrypt, reliability

A few days ago I put a question on SO, without any meaningful answer. Bellow is it on short:

I have a client server program in C that encrypts/decrypts data with mcrypt `C`'s library. The client encrypts the string that wants to send to server, send it, and after the server reads, decrypts it. Bellow are my encrypt and decrypt function:

**encrypt function:**

```
void encrypt(char *es, char *key, char *civ, size_t  length) {

    MCRYPT td;
    int n;

    td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, NULL, MCRYPT_CFB, NULL );
    if (td == MCRYPT_FAILED) {
        log_err(log_opts, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    n = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td);

    char iv[n + 1];
    strncpy(iv, civ, n);
    iv[n] = '\0';

    if ((mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, KEY_SIZE, iv)) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "while trying to do mcrypt_generic_init.");
        exit(1);
    }
    mcrypt_generic(td, es, length);

    if (mcrypt_module_close(td) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "while trying to close module.");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

**decrypt function**

```
void decrypt(char *ds, char *key, char *civ, size_t length) {
    MCRYPT td;
    int n;

    td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TWOFISH, NULL, MCRYPT_CFB, NULL );
    n = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size(td);

    char iv[n + 1];
    strncpy(iv, civ, n);
    iv[n] = '\0';

    if ((mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, KEY_SIZE, iv)) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "trying to do mcrypt_generic_init.");
        exit(1);
    }

    mdecrypt_generic(td, ds, length);
    if (mcrypt_module_close(td) < 0) {
        log_err(log_opts, "while trying to close module.");
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

**My problem:**

There are cases (1 to 10 rate) when a string decrypted on server side but encrypted on client side is not the same like original. Can anyone suggest my where the problem can come from?

Now, I managed to catch a scenario when I'm getting the above bad behavior that I already described. Bellow is my `main` function:

```
int main(void) {

    char *newKey = "P1adEfRuPX0AP2UDmSWHhgS6DaIrE4eb5EEJudC";
    char *iv = "asdfkSSDFAEGasld3G9dkDF0";
    char *s1 = "XZH9ZYKQC9*NYSR6UDUII";
    char *s2 = malloc(STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(s2, s1);
    printf("%s - %s\n", s1, s2);

    encrypt(s2, newKey, iv, strlen(s2));
    decrypt(s2, newKey, iv, strlen(s2));

    if (strncmp(s1, s2, STRING_SIZE) != 0)
        printf("wrong encrypt-decrypt: %s %s\n", s1, s2);

    exit(0);

}
```

Bellow is the output from that `main` function:

```
XZH9ZYKQC9*NYSR6UDUII - XZH9ZYKQC9*NYSR6UDUII
wrong encrypt-decrypt: XZH9ZYKQC9*NYSR6UDUII XZH9ZYKQC
```

**Question:**
Am I doing something wrong, or is that library problematic?

Comment: What is `STRING_SIZE`?

Comment: @ouah the STRING_SIZE is 40.

Comment: And `KEY_SIZE`? Your program is incomplete, please provide all the missing informations.

Comment: @ouah the `KEY_SIZE` is 16.

Comment: Is `civ` your initialization vector?

Comment: I will note that it's a bug to use `strncpy` on raw binary data like encryption keys, IVs, and ciphertexts; these may perfectly legitimately contain `'\0'`. Use `memcpy` instead. I don't think this is what's causing the issue here, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out where the problem comes from. 
In `main` function, I have two lines:

```
encrypt(s2, newKey, iv, strlen(s2));
decrypt(s2, newKey, iv, strlen(s2));
```

The first line is ok, as long as s2 is a well defined string of `char`. But in the second line, `strlen(s2)` can return an erroneous result if the resulted encrypted text contains `'\0'`'s in it.

I just want to say that @chrylis' comment gave me a hint where to search for problem.

In the end, as a rule of thumb, I would say: **IN `C`, YOU MUST NOT USE STRING'S FUNCTIONS ON ENCRYPTED TEXT.**

Thanks to all for assistance!

Comment: More accurately, you must not use string functions on things that don't conform to C's definition of "string". (Such as, yes, arbitrary output of an encryption process.)